# Facebook account kit login does not check authentication on second time

Tags: ios, node.js, facebook

I have integrated Facebook account kit in iOS (front end) and NodeJS as a backend. The implementation working perfectly fine without any issue. 
First time when i try to login using email, i get a email and on tapping on the link sent in the email, the login proceeds.
After the first login immediately i will logout.
Try to login again with the same email ID.
But for the second time account kit is allowing login without sending the email and without clicking on the link.

Is it the default behaviour?

I want the verification email to be sent every time and only after tapping on the link the login should proceed.

Can someone suggest me the workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing this behavior, so I believe it is not default behavior. I am getting a new email every time I try to log in. Are you on the latest SDK? If this still reproduces for you, I would suggest filing a bug to Facebook on your Facebook developer page.

Comment: Yes i am using the latest SDK. I have raised issue in Facebook developer page too.

Comment: Have you tried again? I cannot seem to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

when logout from application release the Facebook session and logout:

```
AKFAccountKit *accountKit;
// set your sdk method to login as public or in the AppDelegate or in a singleton to manage it.

accountKit = [[AKFAccountKit alloc] initWithResponseType:AKFResponseTypeAuthorizationCode];
[accountKit requestAccount:^(id<AKFAccount> account, NSError *error) {

}];

//then when logout form your application try to logout your account manager
//and redefine the controller called for kit login:
[accountKit logOut];
```

Comment: I believe what OP was talking about is Account Kit, which I believe is different from FBSDKLoginManager

Comment: yes i see then i edit the post for the sdk kit used.

Comment: This is the code used : accountKit = [[AKFAccountKit alloc] initWithResponseType: AKFResponseTypeAccessToken]; And even logout is called on the instance. But still it is not working.